# Do I need to update the Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a license Unity 3.x. Now we need to create a simple 2D mobile application. Is compatible Unity 3.x SDK with current mobile API platform (Android, IOS) ?

Comment: For iOS you need Unity 4.6 or higher because 64bit is required by App Store Submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's not really an issue of if you need to but should you.

And you absolutely should.  Unity has released numerous improvements and native support for 2D applications that didn't exist or at least were very rough around the edges prior to 4.  I can't think of any reason why I'd want to stay stuck with Unity 3.x when Unity 5 is readily available.